# React-pdf hook (usepdf) update not working

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I have a pdf that should download when user clicks on a button.
The content for the pdf gets set:

```
const [instance, updateInstance] = usePDF({
    document: (
      <PDFDocument projectsData={projectsData} projectId={projectId} />
    ),
  });
```

When projectsData is updated I call updateInstance. But the content of the PDF still reflects the original projectsData, and not the updated.

I have tried calling updateInstance in a useeffect when projectsData is updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, since you haven't provided more code, however my working code doesn't use parentheses/brackets after the document parameter. So my approach using your code would look like this:

```
const [instance, updateInstance] = usePDF({
    document: <PDFDocument projectsData={projectsData} projectId={projectId} />
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the fix [#2247](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/pull/2247), React-pdf didn't accept any argument to update the instance. Now you can just pass the new Document component as an argument to the updateInstance() function to update and re-render pdf.

You could make use of useEffect hook to watch for changes in projectsData to call the updateInstance. It would look something like this:

```js
const [instance, updateInstance] = usePDF({
  document: (
    <PDFDocument projectsData={projectsData} projectId={projectId} />
  ),
});

useEffect( () => {
  updateInstance(<PDFDocument projectsData={projectsData} projectId={projectId} />)
}, [projectsData])
```